# How to protect author name in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

Can anyone tell me how can I protect my author name in word 2010 after creating my document? It must be protected. No one should edit my name.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a minute to read **[ask]**, then update your question with some details about what you have researched and attempted. We will try to help you with any problem you run into after that.

Answer (score 0):

1. select the all parts of your document that you want this parts are editable,
2. go to file -> protect document -> Restrict editing ->
   in second option"editing restriction" check "allow only this type of editing in this document" then in bottom Tab select "no changes (read only)"
3. in Exceptions (optional) check "everyone"
4. in third option "start enforcement" click on "yes, start enforcing protection"
5. set the password
6. so, some parts that has not been selected are non editable